# Calulating tax of all rows combined

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<input type="text"   value="<?php echo $order_quan; ?>" class="quantity" size='3' "/>
</td>



<input type="text"  value="<?php echo $Price; ?>" class="price" size='10' />
</td>
```

I need help figuring out how to get the total tax of all rows combined.

I have no problem on each individual row getting subtotal, tax, and grand total.

```
  <td width=60px><label class="subtotal" ><?php echo $Total_price; ?></label></td> 

  <td width=60px><label class="tax" ><?php echo $tax; ?></label></td>


  <td width=60px><label class="total_of" ><?php echo $total_of; ?></label></td>
```

Subtotal without tax of all rows combined would go here. I got that working fine

```
<td align= 'left'>Sub Total:  <label class="grandtotal"></label></td>
 </tr>
```

Total tax of all rows combined would go here...not working

```
<td align= 'left'>Total Tax:  <label class="tax_total"></label></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:  I have tried many things but cant figure it out. Any help is much appreciated

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
     CalculateTotal();

    $('.quantity , .price').on('change', function() {


    UpdateTotals(this);
});
});

 function UpdateTotals(elem) {
// This will give the tr of the Element Which was changed
var $container = $(elem).parent().parent();


var quantity = $container.find('.quantity').val();
var price = $container.find('.price').val(); 

var subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
var tax = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price) * .0625;
var total_of = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price) * 1.0625;


$container.find('.subtotal').text(subtotal.toFixed(2));
$container.find('.tax').text(tax.toFixed(2));
 $container.find('.total_of').text(total_of.toFixed(2));


CalculateTotal();
}

function CalculateSubTotals() {
// Calculate the Subtotals when page loads for the 
// first time
var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
var quantity = $('.quantity');
var price= $('.price');
$.each(lineTotals, function(i){
    var tot = parseInt($(quantity[i]).val()) * parseFloat($(price[i]).val());
    $(lineTotals[i]).text(tot.toFixed(2));

   });
}

function CalculateTotal() {
// This will Itearate thru the subtotals and
// claculate the grandTotal and Quantity here
var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
var quantityTotal = $('.quantity');


var grandTotal = 0.0;
var totalQuantity = 0;



$.each(lineTotals, function(i) {
    grandTotal += parseFloat($(lineTotals[i]).text());
    totalQuantity += parseInt($(quantityTotal[i]).val())


});

$('.totalquantity').text(totalQuantity);
$('.grandtotal').text(parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));

}  

</script>
```

Comment: This might belong on the math network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and this seems to work for finding total tax.  But for some reason the tax total is no long fixed to 2 decimal places.

```
   $('.grandtotal').text(parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));
   $('.tax_total').text(.0625*parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The math would be

(item1 + (item1 * .0625)) + (item2 + (item2 * .0625)) + .......+ n = TotalWithTax

The easiest way would be to also add up all the itemtotals without the tax so

item1 + item2 + item3 ......+ n = TotalWithoutTax

TotalWithTax - TotalWithoutTax = TaxTotal.

In your case the TotalWithoutTax would be a sum of all the subtotals.